# How do I use Spring IO Platform BOM and Spring Boot with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle, spring-io

So this `build.gradle` seems to work ok

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


jar {
    baseName = 'entity-api'
    version = '0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons')
    testCompile('junit:junit')
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core')
    testCompile('nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:1.7.5')
}
```

I've tried [adding what's documented](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-using-spring-io-platform-gradle) like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE')
        classpath( 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


jar {
    baseName = 'entity-api'
    version = '0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.3.RELEASE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons')
    testCompile('junit:junit')
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core')
    testCompile('nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:1.7.5')
}
```

but when I do this gradle outputs the following? it's worth saying the auto-conversion from maven doesn't work for me, so I'm learning how to manually convert. How can I fix my gradle build to make use of the spring platform bom?

```
gradle build --stacktrace                                                              slave-vi

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/xenoterracide/IdeaProjects/entity-api/build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'entity-api'.
> org/gradle/mvn3/org/apache/maven/model/building/ModelBuildingException

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
 org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'entity-api'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:72)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:153)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:491)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:89)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:123)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:33)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:100)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:94)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/mvn3/org/apache/maven/model/building/ModelBuildingException
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin.class$(DependencyManagementPlugin.groovy)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin.$get$$class$io$spring$gradle$dependencymanagement$maven$EffectiveModelBuilder(DependencyManagementPlugin.groovy)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin.apply(DependencyManagementPlugin.groovy:79)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin.apply(DependencyManagementPlugin.groovy)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware$apply.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_99h9uwt24qv8u37y4ugf5nxl6.run(/home/xenoterracide/IdeaProjects/entity-api/build.gradle:13)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.mvn3.org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException
    ... 65 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.328 secs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a breaking API change in Gradle 2.5 that affects the dependency management plugin. Upgrade to the latest version, 0.5.3.RELEASE, which works around the problem.

I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-io/platform/issues/260) to update the Platform's documentation. Thank you for bringing the problem to my attention.